# Delete from cursor to end of line in vim command-mode

Tags: vim

In vim, I can use `ctrl-u` to delete all characters to the left of my cursor in command mode. For example:

```
:hello |there
:|there
```

Is there a way to delete all characters to the right of my cursor? For example:

```
:hello |there
:hello |
```

If not, what might be a reasonable mapping to do this? The only thing I could think of is something a bit hairy, such as:

```
:onoremap <c-k> <Delete><Delete><Delete><Delete><Delete><Delete><Delete><Delete><Delete><Delete>...
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Insert mode default keys in vim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62520603/insert-mode-default-keys-in-vim)

Comment: @phd -- no this one is specifically for command mode (the other one wouldn't work).

Comment: `cnoremap <c-k> <c-\>egetcmdline()[:getcmdpos()-2]<CR>`

Comment: @Matt -- so cool, thanks. Want to put that into an answer and I can accept that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
cnoremap <c-k> <c-\>egetcmdline()[:getcmdpos()-2]<CR>
```

See `:h c_CTRL-\_e`, `:h getcmdline()` and `:h getcmdpos()`.